# Keep with T or change to C in verb to derived word conversion

Tags: verbs, nouns

I'm doing some verb to derived word conversions and I'm struggling with keeping the T or converting it to a C in some verbs ended with T:

> Exhibit -> Exhibition
>
> Perfect -> Perfection
>
> Benefit -> **Beneficial**

I have done a bit of research on *beneficial* and [that's what I've found](http://thegrammarexchange.infopop.cc/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/340600179/m/625105871), no common patterns at all.

Is there any rule to make this conversion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### -tial/-cial

I found a site that offers a rule of thumb for spelling words ending in *-tial/-cial* which doesn't even require you to know the spelling of the related verb. It is

> Use -cial after a vowel, like after the vowel ‘o’ in *s**o**cial,* ‘e’ in
>   *sp**e**cial,* ‘i’ in *benef**i**cial*
>
> Use -tial after a consonant, especially,
>   after ‘n’ in *substa**n**tial, esse**n**tial,* ‘r’ in *pa**r**tial*
>
> [...]
>
> Memorise/memorize these seven exceptions:
>   *financial, commercial, provincial, initial, spatial, palatial, controversial*

(from [www.howtospell.co.uk](http://howtospell-letterpatterns.co.uk/cial-tial/), by Joanne Rudling)

This list of exceptions is probably sufficient for common words. You should know that it is not comprehensive; it excludes for example *adventitial, solstitial, preputial*; *internuncial, uncial*;
and probably also some other rare words. Despite the presence of these exceptions, this does seem to be a real trend, based on a comparison of [words that end in -*tial*](http://www.morewords.com/ends-with/tial/) and [words that end in -*cial*](http://www.morewords.com/ends-with/cial/) (Morewords.com).

### -tion/-cion

There are only **two** common words in English that end in *-cion*: *suspicion* (related to the verb *suspect*) and *coercion* (related to the verb *coerce*). There are many words spelled with *-tion,* which can come after vowel letters (as in *creation*) or consonant letters (as in *perception*).

You might also be interested in the answer to this question about [when to use the spellings *-sion, -⁠tion*  and *-cion.*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/244078/when-are-tion-sion-and-cion-used)

Comment: Seems so interesting , I'll take a look at it, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The first poster was right (but not helpful) when he said this is an 'irregular' formation. 
So I don't have a rule to give you,  but at least there is an explanation for the irregularity; some forms of the words benefit have always had a 'c' in them.

http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=benefit&allowed_in_frame=0

So this isn't a weird case of adding a 't',  it's a case of benefice losing its 'c' over time.

http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=beneficial&allowed_in_frame=0