# Why is it "practitioner" and not "practicioner"?

Tags: etymology

This is one of those questions that just pop into your head when using a word; in this case, "practitioner".

The OED defines a practitioner thus:

> **practitioner** *noun*
>
> a. A person engaged in the practice of medicine; a physician, surgeon, pharmacist, etc.

Given that a practitioner is one who is 'engaged in the practi**c**e' of something, why is it not spelt "practi**c**ioner"? Is it to do with the practice being practi**s**ed?

Comment: I am no expert but I would make an educated guess that the spelling reflects pronunciation here. It could also be an orthographical convention: can you think of many words ending in 'cion' or 'cioner' in modern English? Whereas there are so many words ending in 'tion' and 'tioner' -- some already in this comment, and it occurred naturally! *To condi**tion** the air we use an air-condi**tioner.***

Comment: @EnglishStudent That is a good point (RE: orthography), though I (and I imagine many others) (would) pronounce "-tion" and "-cion" the same way: *-shen*

Comment: Not that the pronunciation would differ: but I think (almost) all words ending with 'shen' sound would be spelt with 'tion' as an orthographic conven**tion.** Interestingly, the -cion spelling seems to be used in some other European languages including Spanish (I think), but the words often have a diacritic and the pronunciation might possibly not be *-shen.*

Comment: Closely related: [When are 'tion', 'sion', and 'cion' used](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/244078)

Comment: @sumelic Thanks for that link. It didn't pop up when I performed a search for similar questions.

Comment: English is the way it is because of centuries of people making it up as they go along!  No committee agreed to spell that word that way, and they certainly didn't document their thought processes.

Comment: @sumelic It's similar enough that you might consider marking it as a duplicate of the linked question, whose answer by Josh would be excellent for OP here.

Comment: Not especially helpful, but it appears that it used to have a "c" (a very long time ago). I couldn't tell you why it changed - maybe because of pronunciation, maybe to make it less "French"... See [here](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/practitioner) (under word origin) for example. It also has an unnecessary "er" on the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Originally, it was spelled **practicioner**.  OED provides examples of this spelling as recently as 1735.  This was probably the original spelling based on its etymons:  *practician n.; French practicien*

> 1735    In Physick there are, and have been many happy and lucky **Practicioners** who knew not so much as the Christ-cross Row.

- South-Carolina Gazette · 1732–1775.

The change to *-tion* was likely part of a switch to the Latin suffix which uses a *t*, and which became a standard spelling for such words that had obsolete forms spelled *-cion*. OED's entry on *coercion* offers a foot-note clue.

> The current spelling [coercion] is deceptive, suggesting formation < coerce + -ion. This no doubt led to the retention of the c **when all other words with the mediaeval spelling -cion, were altered to the Latin type in -tion.**

[Wiktionary confirms this explanation](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-tion) with added detail:

> The Middle English *-cioun* became *-tion* in Modern English under the influence of the Middle French *-tion* **and original Latin spellings**.

The two remaining exceptions are "suspicion" and, as discussed, "coercion."

Comment: There isn't actually any Latin form of "practitioner" with "t", though. It's a post-Latin coinage based on "practic-"

Comment: @sumelic in my post I wrote "The **change** to *-tion*."  My point is that Latin spellings influenced the switch from *-cion* to *-tion*, per the sources mentioned.  I'll edit the post to make that more clear.

Comment: @sumelic a valid point, I think it prompted a worthwhile edit.

Answer (score 1):

Just to support RaceYouAnytime's answer, and the explanation of analogy, I thought I would post to add an example of a similar spelling I found recently in an old book, *The life of a satyrical pvppy, called Nim who worrieth all those satyrists he knowes, and barkes at the rest,* by T.M. (accessed from Early English Books Online).

It uses the spelling "[Physitians](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/t/text/pageviewer-idx?cc=eebo;c=eebo;idno=a70659.0001.001;node=A70659.0001.001%3A4.2;seq=15;vid=106928;page=root;view=text)" for "Physician's". The Oxford English Dictionary lists a number of other variant spellings of "physician" that use "ti" instead of "ci". Of course, "physician" is related to words like "physical", and doesn't have any "t" in its etymology.